# Access the Ubuntu Server Guide from command line

Tags: command-line, server, documentation

Ubuntu Server has a great guide online: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs

Is there a way I could have that documentation directly from my command line without accessing the web? Something equivalent to `man` or `info` would be ideal.

Comment: Well, it is a collection of HTML documents and therefore hard to render on the command line, but you could always install [lynx](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lynx) and open the URL with that from the command line.

Comment: Considering they have a pdf version, there’s a good chance they also have some kind of source document from which one could derive other formats.

Answer (score 0):

- PDF

  Download the free available [Ubuntu Server PDF](https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/c5a3ce24-ubuntu-server-guide.pdf).
  How to view pdfs from terminal is discussed in this forum: 
  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36201/pdf-viewer-for-command-line-only
- Download the html
  Try to download the page via wget (`sudo apt install wget`):

  ```
  wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension \
    --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --domains website.org \
    --no-parent https://ubuntu.com/server/docs
  ```